# Cant increase width of textbox in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a form-group to wrap my controls in but i cant see how I to increase the width of the textboxes at the min they are very small how do i control the size of the textbox to be full width  txtIVACode.

I tried style width and put the vaue to 80% but that did not increase the size of text box?.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Is Joint Application</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <label class="checkbox">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<telerik:RadCheckBox ID="chkIsJointApplication" runat="server"></telerik:RadCheckBox>
       </label>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">IVA Code</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtIVACode"   runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Add the class `form-control` to the text input.

Comment: @Tump how does that allow me to increase width ?

Comment: @Tump I have tried from-control and form control lg but the width is still the same

Comment: `.form-control` would make the input 100% width of the container

Comment: Example: http://www.bootply.com/r2XzJVfsBR